# Amazon CloudSearch : first search after some idle time is slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I am currently evaluating if I can use Amazon CloudSearch for our search need instead of Elastic Search. 
Right now, I just have about 4K small documents for my testing purpose. Let's if I try to performance the search after a good 2-3 hours, the first search is about 8 to 10 times slower compared to the subsequent searches. The first search after some idle time takes about about 300ms where as the subsequent searches take about 40ms. I am not using the same search terms in the first and subsequent searches, so dont think the subsequent searches are faster due to cached results.

Please note that if I change my instance type to search.m3.xlarge or search.m3.2xlarge instead of default, the response of first search is not all that bad. I tried to look into the documentation if it is an expected behavior, but could not find any. Can someone throw some light on this please?

Comment: You should know that CloudSearch hasn't seen an update in 5 years, so it's clearly just being treated by AWS as a supported tool, but it is not actively maintained like Elasticsearch is.  The only reason you would want to use CloudSearch instead of Elasticsearch is if you aren't comfortable using the command line or writing scripts to manage your search instance.

Comment: could you solve this problem? I'm having delays of around 10 seconds in first search after some idle time!

Comment: After having discussions with amazon we have learnt that cloudsearch is not in active development anymore though they are still supporting the existing customers and ready to fix any bugs and vulnerabilities. So we had decided to move on to other search solutions. Sorry about the delay in reverting back on this. Thanks.